# nginx rewrite file name on secure connection

Tags: http, https, nginx, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite the file name on https in nginx configuration?

for example I have

/public/abc.html
/public/abc-s.html

but I want user who access `https://mydomain/abc.html` load `abc-s.html`, while `http://mydomain/abc-s.html` load `abc.html`.

thx

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by a series of regular expressions; example:

```
  set $hasdashs u; # if we don't match .html we don't want to do a rewrite
  if ($uri ~* "^(.*)\.html$") { # are we looking at a .html page? If so, get the base name
    set $hasdashs n;
    set $shorturi "$1";
  }
  if ($uri ~ "^(.*)-s\.html$") { # are we looking at a secure page? Get the base name without -s
    set $hasdashs y;
    set $shorturi "$1";
  }
  set $schemecheck "$scheme$hasdashs";

  if ($schemecheck = "httpy") { #we're using http and looking at a secure page
    rewrite . "${shorturi}.html" redirect;
  }
  if ($schemecheck = "httpsn") { #we're using https and looking at an insecure page
    rewrite . "${shorturi}-s.html" redirect;
  }
```

Note that this has to be in the server block and **not** the location block of the configuration. Tested on NGINX 1.2.1.